# Discord Bot can't delete messages from dms

Tags: python, discord.py

I forgot to add a bot-check in my code before testing the bot, and my discord dm channel looks horrible. I'm trying to have the bot go in and delete the messages, but I can't find a command that will work for that.
`message.delete()` only works for the message that was sent last, and `channel.purge` seems to work only for messages sent in a server, not dms.
I've already looked through the discord API references, but either I missed something, or I just can't find the command that I need. I've left links for both dm and regular channels, but I really  want to clear the mess that I inadvertnetly made:

[discord dm channel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=user#dmchannel) [discord regular channel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=user#textchannel)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're probably only deleting the last message because the `message` variable is the one that was just passed to the bot. Instead, you need to store all the messages in an array `messages` from which you can run something like this:

```py
for message in messages: await message.delete()
```

Comment: `message.delete` is a coroutine, needs to be awaited

Comment: I've restarted the bot multiple times since the malfunction, so the messages aren't stored there any longer

Comment: In that case you would have to find each of the messages sent by the bot by accessing the message history and then loop through it as shown

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by manually getting the id of every message, putting it into an array, and using `await message.delete()` in a loop to delete all of the messages